# Should I create a new Flurry analytics app id if I upgrade my app version?

Tags: iphone, flurry

I want to analyse the user behavior in different version of my app, should I create different app id in Flurry  analytics like DemoApp1.0, DemoApp1.1 etc, 
Or Flurry analytics will automatically records the different version?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. you should not create a separate app id, nor would any analytics service require you to create a seaprate id.

Havign the same id helps you to see the numbers and compare versions etc.

(btw, all this should be there in flurry faq)

Answer (score 0):

No, I think flurry has application's version management function.

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate, before he Flurry startSesstion call, try:

```
[FlurryAnalytics setAppVersion:@"1.2"];
```